# Memcache and Server side caching. When to use what?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I want to ask when to use Memcache and when to use normal Rails caching techniques  like page, action  and fragment caching. 
Which is useful when?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up two things Memcache and Rails caching techniques. Memcache is a caching server which could also be used with any of the Rails caching techniques. Of all the techniques, Rails fragment caching is considered the best as it enables you to cache the block on a particular page, on a contrary, action caching and page caching caches the whole page, which is not always desirable. Fragment caching is considered best as now a days the content of the pages are so dynamic that certain parts of the page can be cached and other cannot.